# Spring Boot - Load bean only if it is enabled by a property

Tags: spring-boot, import, javabeans, aop, depends

I have a **Spring Boot application** with different submodules which also contains spring components.
And in the main web modules I use 70% of the beans from the submodules. It depends on the application.yml properties, if the property group (which points to a bean) is enabled or not.

First I wanted to create Aspect-s, so when a method of a bean (which is not enabled by it's property) is called, then throw an exception. This solution could work, but then I would need to create Aspect classes, method annotations, import more and more dependencies.

So I am just wondering, would be there any other easier solution to disable a bean, or do not load at all to the spring boot container?

I would imagine something like `@DependsOn`, but for this you need to give a name of a bean name, but you cannot use this annotation to work with yml property.

Other easy solution is to `@Bean` or `@Import` every bean I want to managed by spring container, instead of `@Import` everything once from submodules, but then it is a static setting, cannot be overwrite by a single property from yml.

Comment: Add `@ConditionalOnProperty` to that bean.

Comment: Have you considered using [Spring Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles) to limit when beans are loaded?

Comment: `@ConditionalOnProperty` is exactly what I need, thanks @M. Denium
Add as an answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring introduced the [concept of conditionals](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-conditional) quite some time ago. Spring Boot uses this to a great extend to conditionally enable features. It even created a lot of [conditional rules](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition) which you can use.

One of those rules is the **conditional on a property** rule. To use this rule add an [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) annotation to your bean. Now it will only be included if said property is enabled or has the specific value.

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="your.property.name")
```