# Is it worthy using AOP in a Spring-boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-aop

A few days ago, I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320494/is-there-a-newer-approach-to-spring-aop-and-mockito/58321018#58321018) asking whether there is a newer approach to Spring AOP and mockito.

While I understand how to use AOP, I am still missing on its returned value. The whole endeavour has shown me that it's not really popular - at least there aren't that many recent posts.

If I comment out the annotations `@Aspect` and `@Configuration` in my `LoggingAspect` class, effectively rendering it non-aop, all my tests are green. If I switch it back on, I start getting a load of NullPointerExceptions and loads of other errors on my mocked test classes.

I wonder if it is worth the hassle.

**EDIT** adding more detail from my specific implementation.

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class EndpointController {

    private EndpointService endpointService;

    @Autowired    
    public EndpointController(EndpointService endpointService) {
        this.endpointService = endpointService;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/endpoint", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private @ResponseBody EndpointResponse doSomething(//... //, @RequestBody SomeObject someObject) throws Exception {
        return endpointService.doSomething(someObject);
    }
}
```

In my test class, I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EndpointControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldBeSuccessfulAccessingTheEndpoint() throws Exception {
        SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject(// values //);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String payload = mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/endpoint").contentType(MediaType.APPLICTION_JSON).content(payload)).andExpect(status().isOK));
    }
}
```

It fails and throws a NullPointerException. When debugging, the `endpointService` is always null.

Comment: The answer is obvious: you have to satisfy the controller dependency.  Inject in an instance of  EndpointService.  Your test has to do it in setup.  Can be either a real or mock implementation - probably mock.

Comment: This is a limitation of proxy based AOP, it will only work for public methods. Spring Boot by default forces cglib proxies, which work by subclassing the method and override/extend the public method to which AOP applies. It will wrap a configured object, and first call the interceptor then pass on to the actual object. However in your case you have a private method. A private method cannot be overriden and thus it will be called on the proxy, instead of eventually the real object. The proxy has no dependencis injected and thus it is null. Make the method public to fix.

Comment: This question is primarily opinion-based and thus off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AOP is as valid as ever.  It's used for transactions, logging, metrics, etc.

I think there was period where it might have been overused as decorators.

Production and testing are different matters.

If you're unit testing a class, it suggests that you aren't testing the aspects.  You could make those aspects conditional based on profile.

If the proper operation of your object depends on the aspect, because it modifies the input, perhaps you should rethink.

Comment: For now, we aim using it only for logging. But as I mentioned, it breaks the tests in place.

Comment: What does breaking look like?  NPE?  Can you make the aspect conditional so it's not applied for test profile or a property?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182570/spring-boot-load-bean-only-if-it-is-enabled-by-a-property

Comment: For some of the failing tests, the test is supposed to hit an endpoint in a `@InjectMocks` annotated controller, but the `@Mock` annotated service is null.

Comment: That's not a problem with aspects, it's your mock.

Comment: Doesn't mean you should dismiss the idea of AOP.  It's perfectly valid.  Maybe you have to write better tests.

Comment: I agree with the idea of AOP. The part about writing better tests is the tricky one, though... this is a 20+ micro-services project and I would really do not want to re-write other peoples tests... Thank you for your inputs, thought!

Comment: "I am still missing on its returned value" - this sounds like a dismissal to me.  NPE is easy to fix.  Post your JUnit test code.  Perhaps that will give a clue.

Comment: By that, I meant that I had not yet seen the value, but I got your point. I have edited the question to add something very close to the implementation I am working.

Answer (score 1):

AOP is great for **cross-cutting concerns**:

- Logging (we use it for access and performance logging)
- Validation (such as used by Bean Validation, JSR-380)
- Transactional scopes (built into frameworks such as JEE and Spring)
- Security checks (e.g. Shiro)
- and many more.

It could be used for other purposes, such as extending/wrapping existing functionality, though that is definitely not something I'd recommend, and fortunately never became popular, as it seems.

Comment: My problems with it concern mocking `@Service` classes mostly.